# how to run function on Button click in SharePoint apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, apps-development, office365apis, office-365-develop-tool

- I had a table in "PlaceHolderMain" of Default.aspx with some text
  boxes and buttons .
- And written a function to save list items in app.js file .Can any one
  help me and know how can I call the function on button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

Your html in Default.aspx page:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="DoSomething()"/>
```

Your function in App.js:

```
function DoSomething()
{}
```